# Proper way to change axis in plot tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am trying to reconstruct the image below in tikz, and I think I have done a fairly decent job.

The problem is that my code is a mess. Is there any simple clean way to produce this image?

[image: Maanedpris]

My main problem was the axis, and somewhat the scaling. Also the nodes are a huge mess ^^

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.02cm,y=0.02cm,scale=1]
  \tkzInit[ymin=-40,ymax=390,xmin=-40,xmax=540]
  \tkzClip
\draw[help lines,ultra thin,dashed,gray!50!white] (-50,-50) grid (550,400);
\coordinate [label=below right:{50}] (x_1) at (50,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:{}] (B) at (0,390);
\coordinate [label=above right:{\Large $y$}] (U) at (0,350);
\coordinate [label=above left:{\Large $x$}] (A) at (540,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:{50}] (x_1) at (50,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:{100}] (x_2) at (100,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:{150}] (x_3) at (150,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:{200}] (x_4) at (200,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:{250}] (x_5) at (250,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:{300}] (x_6) at (300,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:{350}] (x_7) at (350,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:{400}] (x_8) at (400,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:{450}] (x_9) at (450,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:{500}] (x_10) at (500,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:{0}] (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=above left:{50}] (y_1) at (0,50);
\coordinate [label=above left:{100}] (y_2) at (0,100);
\coordinate [label=above left:{150}] (y_3) at (0,150);
\coordinate [label=above left:{200}] (y_4) at (0,200);\\
\coordinate [label=above left:{250}] (y_5) at (0,250);
\coordinate [label=above left:{300}] (y_6) at (0,300);
\coordinate [label=above left:{350}] (y_7) at (0,350);
\coordinate [label=above left:{\bf Kostnader per m\aa ned (kroner)}] (R) at (310,350);
\coordinate [label=above left:{\bf Ringetid (minutter)}] (K) at (540,20);
\tkzDefPoint(0,-50){C} 
\tkzDefPoint(-50,0){D}
\tkzDefPoint(0,87.50){S}
\tkzDefPoint(500,337.50){T}
\tkzDrawSegment[thick,-stealth](D,A)
\tkzDrawSegment[thick,-stealth](C,B)
\tkzDrawSegment[ultra thick,red](S,T)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: My attempt to create the plot]

My main question is, if there is a simpler way to create the axis. (nodes?)

Comment: You really should be using [tag:pgfplots] for this.  There are plenty of examples on the site.

Comment: Another vote for pgfplots. I did an example of one [earlier today](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35537/diagramming-workflow-in-latex/35549#35549). The [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) for the package is extremely helpful and provides lots of examples to work with.

Comment: I am reading thrugh the documentation now, it seems as a very powerful tool. Alas I do not see anything about changing the default axis... I am perhaps blind. A

Comment: Added an answer for you to have a play with. I really enjoy using pgfplots, so I think you're going to have fun with it.

Comment: Yes  but `pgfplots` is the recommended tool but I have also fun to write codes with my packages. The code of the OP is not very optimized. `tkz-euclide`  is used to create geometrical drawings. `tkz-base` is a tool for drawing with a cartesian coordinate system. You can define your axes with `\tkzAxeX` and `tkzAxeY`with the options `xstep` and `ystep`(see my answer).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a rough version of the plot you want for you to play with.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=newest}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    grid=major,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={->},
    xlabel={$x$ Ringetid (minutter)},
    ylabel={$y$ Kostnader per måned (kroner)},
    ytick={0,50,...,350},
    xtick={0,50,...,500},
    ymin=-10,
    ymax=370,
    xmin=-10,
    xmax=520,
]
\addplot[color=red,thick] coordinates {
            (0, 75)
            (500, 340)
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which will give you this (thanks to Torbjørn for tricks to make this more succinct code):

[image: Simple pgfplot]

It's not exactly the same, but you can get it there with a bit more tweaking.

Comment: A little easier way of defining the labels: `xtick={0,50,...,500}, ytick={0,50,...,350}`. You don't have to specify the `labelticks` as well.  And you can add `grid style={dashed}` to get the dashed grid.

Comment: Noted. Those are a hangover from a plot which had lots of decimal places (very fine grain) which pgfplots approximated to 1. I stupidly updated them instead of taking them out, I'll take those out now. I left the grid style out on purpose though. Better to encourage exploration.

Comment: You can also plot a function with `\addplot{0.54*x+70};`. You just need to add `domain=0:500,no markers` to the axis options.

Comment: @percusse: Using `domain` on its own doesn't work, because it spaces the ticks too far apart. I've updated the plot with what I think is the minimal to do this as the original figure specifies. As far as I can see, the easiest way to define a line is with two points, so in this case I see no reason to use a function.

Comment: Ah, actually I missed that part of what Torbørn was trying to tell me earlier.

Comment: Well actually, you could use `axis lines=middle` instead of separate statements for `x` and `y`. Similar for the arrow style of the axis, `inner axis line style={->}`. (Sorry for the nagging, forgot to mention these earlier.)

Comment: Now I didn't know those two...

Comment: Added, with an acknowledgement. I'm still keeping the dashed grid out though. Wouldn't do to solve the problem too exactly!

Comment: Well, I didn't really know the second one myself, I just took a quick look at the manual ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure I knew most of this once, but somehow got lazy and fell into the trap of just adjusting code for a plot a little bit each time I needed a new one.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with you, `pgfplots`is the recommended tool to draw such graphics and `tkz-euclide`is a tool for some specific geometrical drawings but it's possible to draw a simple line with `tkz-base`or with `tkz-fct`. `tkz-base`can define coordinates to draw with euclide and(or) fct.

version A with `tkz-fct` this package loads `tkz-base`

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath,tkz-fct}    

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=500,ymax=350,xstep=50,ystep=50] % to get the good coordinates
\tkzAxeX[label=$x$ Ringetid (minutter),above left=10pt]
\tkzAxeY[label=$y$ Kostnader per måned (kroner),below right=30pt]
\tkzGrid
\tkzFct[color = red, domain =0:500]{75+0.55*\x}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

version B with only `tkz-base`

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath,tkz-base}   

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=500,ymax=350,xstep=50,ystep=50]
\tkzAxeX[label=$x$ Ringetid (minutter),above left=10pt]
\tkzAxeY[label=$y$ Kostnader per måned (kroner),below right=30pt]
\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoint(0,75){A} 
\tkzDefPoint(500,340){B} 
\tkzDrawSegment[color=red](A,B) 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the two versions, the result is :

[image]

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I wrote `tkz-fct` for personal use  while `pgfplots` was not yet written. Now the good way is to use `pgfplots` but with `tkz` or with `pgfplots` you need to look at the documentation. euclide and fct both use base to create drawings.