# Using PSTricks to plot from a data file

Tags: pstricks, graphs

I would like to know how to use PSTricks to read and plot data from a text data file e.g.

```
8   98826   year 2008
9   104925  year 2009
10  140153  year 2010
11  178414  year 2011
```

And three further questions:

1. Can comments like "year 2008" added after the two first columns be ignored in PSTricks?
2. And is it possible to add a general comment and headings to the data file while still make it possible for PSTricks to read the data file?
3. Is PSTricks suitable to plot large amount of data? I do not know how large is large but say more than 100 points. I typically use Matlab for my plots but I am considering other options that are closer to LaTeX.

Comment: Would a PGFplots solution be interesting as well?

Comment: I see from the PGFplot manual that this pacakge has much to offer. Does it work with TeXLive also? Yes you are welcome to provide a PGFplot solution here but I cannot guarantee that I will accept your solution if others will come up with PStricks-based solutions here.

Comment: It's a standard part of TeXLive now. Check out [my recent answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35549/9043) with an introduction to pgfplots, including how to use a file.

Comment: You may need to index by column number if there are no column headers. Do this like `\addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {datafile.dat};`

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt Thanks for the link. Yes PGFplot seems very elegant to use and your example works with my TeXLive.

Comment: All I ask for is an up vote (if you find it useful). ;)

Comment: Look at this page of the [PSTricks website](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/DataExamples). They mention an example with 1000 data records. The documentation for pst-plots and pst-add will help. You can find it on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody has attempted a solution I'll mention: 1. According to the PST-plot documentation (page 6), comments can be added after the first 2 columns but you'll need to put a percent sign before it. 2. Headers can be added; to ignore them you use the `ignoreLines` command (page 58) so if your header is 20 lines, then `ignoreLines=20` is used. Finally, the PSTrick page I commented on above and the documentation from PST-plot (page 59-60) mentions an example with 1000 data records. Since you indicate you are using page 6 of the documentation says the `\dataplot` command is for lists of data created by other programs. Maybe you don't need to consider other options. I haven't used this package much; I played around and got this (light comments included):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\readdata[ignoreLines=1]{\mydata}{ExData} %ignores 1 line
\psset{xAxisLabel=My x-Axis,yAxisLabel=My y-Axis, xAxisLabelPos={c,-3},yAxisLabelPos={-2,c}}
% the position of your axes labels can be adjusted by changing, for example xAxisLabelPos={c,-2}
\pstScalePoints(1,.00001){}{} %the y values have been multiplied by 1/10^5  so they'll show
\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame,Dy=1,ylabelFactor=\cdot 10^5,Dx=1,ticksize=5pt 0](1,0)(11,7){10cm}{8cm}%the labels have been adjusted to reflect the 1/10^5
%the (1,0) starts the first record on the y-axis 
\listplot[linecolor=red, linewidth=1pt,showpoints=true]{\mydata}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

The data file (ExData) has this as its contents:

```
A useless header
1   234611  %year 2000
2   645511  %year 2001
3  345311  
4  235411 
5   342526  
6   134525 
7  145153  
8   98826   
9   104925 
10  140153  
11  178414
```

Output above [image]

Answer (score 5):

The number of data records is not limited ...

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.data}
8   98826   year 2008
9   104925  year 2009
10  140153  year 2010
11  178414  year 2011 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\readdata{\mydata}{test.data}
\pstVerb{/year {} def }
\pstScalePoints(1,1){}{1.e4 div}

\psset{xAxisLabel=My x-Axis,yAxisLabel=My y-Axis, xAxisLabelPos={c,-1.5},yAxisLabelPos={-0.5,c}}
\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame,Dy=2,Oy=8,Ox=8,ylabelFactor=\cdot 10^4,ticksize=5pt 0](8,8)(11,20){10cm}{8cm}
\listplot[linecolor=red, linewidth=2pt,showpoints,dotstyle=square,
  plotNoMax=2,plotNo=1]{\mydata}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the `\pstVerb` command documented? There's no mention of it in the `pst-plot` documentation.

Comment: I chose DJP's answer as it gives the input from an external file as required by the question but otherwise your two codes are pretty much alike and helpful. 1 vote up.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: All data is read from an external file ...

Comment: @ Herbert. Yes now I can see that you have defined your data before \begin{document} and that you are reading from a file.